# jQuery Mobile Multiple Pages

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm having trouble with multiple pages using jQuery Mobile.

I currently have a few levels of 'pages' inside an index.html file, but I'm having trouble linking 3 layers of pages.

I can link back from a '#home' page to different 'pages' by their id using

```
<a href="#one" data-transition="flip">Page 1</a>
```

without a problem, and then linking to a page further than that, such as

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="info" data-url="info">
```

but I can't then use the same link as before to get to page 'one' with

```
 <a href="#one" data-transition="flip">Page 1</a>.
```

The url in the address bar (Chrome) will change to /#one correctly, but it won't actually process that page. Anyone have any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Does the 'Home' div have an ID of 'home'? Sometimes it's easy to forget the default div ID.

Comment: Does it work in non-mobile? Do you have an example?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I put all my code into jsfiddle for you to look at... then realised it was working there (avoiding some of my local .js files). I then realised it was a plugin I'm using - photoswipe. It was loading on pages, not required and consequently breaking jQuery Mobile. Basically if there are no images for it to use it has a paddy! Thanks for your help :)